# Snowflake Python connector dynamic number of paramteres

Tags: python, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I want to execute Snowflake stored procedure from Python and I've been using snowflake-connector-python==2.7.2.

The problem I'm facing is that I have a variable number of arguments to send to stored procedure. So, I have a dict with params:

```
{
 "run_id": 3,
 "process_id": 1,
 "load_type": "I"
}
```

And I have a Snowflake stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure stage.sp_load_something(
  RUN_ID FLOAT, 
  PROCESS_ID FLOAT,
  LOAD_TYPE VARCHAR)
```

so, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to map dict keys to stored procedure arguments?
2. How can I make it dynamic, so that when I have dict with 5 keys and stored procedure with 5 arguments it still works?
3. How to properly map stored procedure data types?

Comment: For point #2 , I created overloaded  procs  in snowflake and wrote python script based on  # of args to call  procedure . Also maintained same datatypes  during call and in signature. I dont know this would help but thought of throwing an idea. For reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-example-overloading-stored-procedure-names

Comment: thank you for your reply @Anand Unfortunately that is not a problem I'm facing. I have a stored procedure name to execute and dict with N number of params. I need a dynamic way to call that procedure sending it values from dict as input arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something. Why can't one pass the set of key-value pairs as a single object typed parameter and then do the more dynamic handling parts of your task in the procedure itself?

Other than that, as far as I know, a Snowflake stored procedure will have a signature defining what parameters it takes & be defined by that. You can define the same name & have different signatures but then you'd be creating (probably by hand) each individual variation (which would not be very dynamic).

Comment: I just realized that there's a relevant page on this at [Snowflake SQL stored procedure to pass optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335610/snowflake-sql-stored-procedure-to-pass-optional-arguments/74072881).

Check the answer that @greg-pavlik gave.