# Snowflake SQL stored procedure to pass optional arguments

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are working on migrating netezza to snowflake. Netezza stored procedures has a way, where it allows the call of procedure with any number of argument with the help of `PROC_ARGUMENT_TYPES`. Do we have similar function in snowflake as well?

Like

```
c:= PROC_ARGUMENT_TYPES.count;
```

returns the number of argument passed.

Please note: we are working on SQL stored procedures in Snowflake.

Comment: Optional arguments are [supported from v7.41.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71748900/optional-parameters-in-snowflake-stored-procedures/77488673#77488673)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake does not allow procedures or UDFs with an arbitrary number of input parameters. However, it's possible to approximate this capability using any combination of procedure overloading, arrays, objects, and variants.

Here's one example that's using procedure overloading and variants. The first procedure has only the required parameters. The second procedure has the required parameters plus an additional parameter that accepts a variant.

If the calling SQL specifies two parameters, it will call the procedure (overload) with only two parameters in the signature. That procedure in turn just calls the main stored procedure specifying NULL for the third parameter and returns the results.

The main stored procedure with three inputs has a variant for the final input. It can accept an array or an object. An array requires positional awareness of the inputs. An object does not. An object allows passing name/value pairs.

```
create or replace procedure VARIABLE_SIGNATURE(REQUIRED_PARAM1 string, REQUIRED_PARAM2 string)
returns variant
language javascript
as
$$
    var rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText:`call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE(?,?,null)`,binds:[REQUIRED_PARAM1, REQUIRED_PARAM1]});
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
$$;

create or replace procedure VARIABLE_SIGNATURE(REQUIRED_PARAM1 string, REQUIRED_PARAM2 string, OPTIONAL_PARAMS variant)
returns variant
language javascript
as
$$
    var out = {};
    out.REQUIRED_PARAM1 = REQUIRED_PARAM1;
    out.REQUIRED_PARAM2 = REQUIRED_PARAM2;
    out.OPTIONAL_PARAMS = OPTIONAL_PARAMS;
    return out;
$$;

-- Call the SP overload different ways:
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2');
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', array_construct('PARAM3', 'PARAM4', 'PARAM5'));
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', object_construct('PARAM3_NAME', 'PARAM3_VALUE', 'PARAM10_NAME', 'PARAM10_VALUE'));
```

While these SPs are JavaScript, overloading and the use of arrays, objects, and variants works the same way for SQL Script stored procedures.

Comment: So basically we should use procedure overloading . the only problem is we have around 100 of proc and now we will have to get in depth of it of how they are getting called. but if it is the only way.. then it is what it is.. thank you

Comment: I wouldn't use overloading in all cases. Depending on the situation it may be better to use arrays; however, at least at the present there's no option for an arbitrary number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I have noticed about valid notations for this in Snowflake.

To avoid maintaining stored procedure duplicate, overloaded versions, an alternative kludge to overloading might be to require the passing of some sort of a testable falsy variant or a NULL when no additional values are wanted.

```
    -- Call the SP by passing a testable, falsy value:
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2');                     -- This will fail fail without overloading with a matched, 2 string/varchar signature.
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', NULL);               -- This will work.
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', ''::variant);        -- This will work.
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', array_construct());  -- This will work.
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', object_construct()); -- This will work.
```

Of course, `array_construct('PARAM3', 'PARAM4', 'PARAM5'))` can also be written as `parse_json('["PARAM3", "PARAM4", "PARAM5"]')`.

Similarly, `object_construct('PARAM3_NAME', 'PARAM3_VALUE', 'PARAM10_NAME', 'PARAM10_VALUE')` can be written also as `parse_json('{"PARAM3_NAME": "PARAM3_VALUE", "PARAM10_NAME",  "PARAM10_VALUE"}')`.

Neither of these alternatives gives us anything that useful unless you just like parse_json() more than the other two functions.

Also, I am not sure if this has always worked (maybe Greg Pavlik knows?), but the notation for these variant types can be abbreviated a little bit by constructing an object with `{}` or an array with `[]` and thus be made slightly cleaner and more readable.

To explore the notations that Snowflake will accept, here are examples of code that will work:

```
-- Call the SP using different notations:
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', (select array_construct('PARAM3', 'PARAM4', 'PARAM5')));           -- Make the notation awkward & hard to read.
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', (select ['PARAM3', 'PARAM4', 'PARAM5']));                          -- Make the notation awkward & hard to read.
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', ['PARAM3', 'PARAM4', 'PARAM5']);                                   -- This also works & is easy to read.
call VARIABLE_SIGNATURE('PARAM1', 'PARAM2', {'PARAM3_NAME': 'PARAM3_VALUE', 'PARAM10_NAME': 'PARAM10_VALUE'}); -- This also works & is easy to read.
```